# WooCommerce's Ajax "load more" button and Ajax filters

Tags: ajax, woocommerce

I found this code for WooCommerce's `load more` button. It works fine at first but when I filter the products with an Ajax plugin the button doesn't respond at all.

The link to the code: https://github.com/bassscape/woocommerce-ajax-load-more-products

```
<?php
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // [1] Enqueue scripts and add localized parameters
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pp_custom_scripts_enqueue' );
    function pp_custom_scripts_enqueue() {
    
        $theme = wp_get_theme(); // Get the current theme version numbers for bumping scripts to load
    
        // Make sure jQuery is being enqueued, otherwise you will need to do this.
    
        // Register custom scripts
        wp_register_script( 'woocommerce_load_more', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts/load_more.js', array( 'jquery' ), $theme['Version'], true); // Register script with dependencies and version in the footer
    
        // Enqueue scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('woocommerce_load_more');
    
        
        global $wp_query; // Make sure important query information is available
        
        // Use wp_localize_script to output some variables in the html of each WordPress page
        // These variables/parameters are accessible to the load_more.js file we enqueued above
        $localize_var_args = array(
            'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
            'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
            'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
    
        );
        wp_localize_script( 'woocommerce_load_more', 'wp_js_vars', $localize_var_args );
    
    }
    
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // [3] Load More Products with AJAX
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'pp_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'pp_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
    function pp_loadmore_ajax_handler(){
    
        // prepare our arguments for the query
        $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
        $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
        $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
    
        query_posts( $args );
    
        if( have_posts() ) :
    
            // run the loop
            while( have_posts() ): the_post();
    
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );  // As we are loaded WooCommerce products we use wc_get_template_part 
                //echo '<p>'.get_the_title().'</p>'; // for the test purposes comment the line above and uncomment the below one
    
            endwhile;
    
        endif;
        die; // Exit the script, wp_reset_query() required!
    
    }


    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // [4] Remove WooCommerce pagination as we do not need it any more
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10 );
    
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // [5] Add in our load more products container and button
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'pp_woocommerce_products_load_more', 9 );
    function pp_woocommerce_products_load_more(){
    
        echo '<div id="container_products_more">';
            woocommerce_product_loop_start();
            woocommerce_product_loop_end();
            //echo '<pre>' . var_export($wp_query, true) . '</pre>'; // For testing
            if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) {
                echo '<div id="pp_loadmore_products" class="button">LOAD MORE</div>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    
    }


    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // [6] Add a new class to the woocommerce_product_loop, we need this to target it with jQuery in load_more.js
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    function woocommerce_product_loop_start() { echo '<ul class="products products_archive_grid">'; }
    function woocommerce_product_loop_end() { echo '</ul>'; }
    
?>
```

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";
    $(function() {

        //-----------------------------------------------------
        // [2] Ajax load products - On Click
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        $('#pp_loadmore_products').click(function(){

            var button = $(this),
                data = {
                'action': 'loadmore',
                'query': wp_js_vars.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
                'page' : wp_js_vars.current_page
            };

            $.ajax({
                url : wp_js_vars.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
                data : data,
                related_products : 'no',
                type : 'POST',
                beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                    button.addClass('loading');
                    button.text('LOADING ...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
                },
                success : function( data ){
                    if( data ) {
                        //console.log('current_page: ' + wp_js_vars.current_page + ' max_page: ' + wp_js_vars.max_page);
                        $('#container_products_more .products_archive_grid').append( data ); // where to insert posts
                        button.removeClass('loading');
                        button.text( 'LOAD MORE' );
                        wp_js_vars.current_page++;

                        if ( wp_js_vars.current_page == wp_js_vars.max_page )
                            button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button
                    } else {
                        button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
}(jQuery));
```

I would be grateful for all your suggestions.

I can't find the solution to this and i need your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem:

```
$('#container_products_more .products_archive_grid').append( data );
```

When you change the `innerHTML` like that, you lose the event handlers.

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Indeed, it works");
    this.value="now it will not work";
    this.parentNode.innerHTML += "some text";
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="it works">
</div>
```

Now that we have seen this, it is clear that the change of inner HTML destroys event handlers. So how can we cope with this issue?

## 1. onclick :)

```js
function myClick(that) {
    alert("Indeed, it works");
    that.parentNode.innerHTML += "some text";
};
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="it works" onclick="myClick(this)">
</div>
```

## 2. Recreating the event :(

```js
function myClick() {
    alert("Indeed, it works");
    this.parentNode.innerHTML += "some text";
    document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", myClick);
}
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", myClick);
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="it works">
</div>
```

This would work, but I don't recommend it, because it overcomplicates your code.

## 3. .on()

```js
function myClick() {
    alert("Indeed, it works");
    this.parentNode.innerHTML += "some text";
}
$("#foo").on("click", "#mybutton", myClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="it works">
    </div>
</div>
```

## 4. Separate the volatile HTML from the acionable items

```js
function myClick() {
    alert("Indeed, it works");
    document.getElementById("volatile").innerHTML += "some text";
}
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", myClick);
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="it works">
    <div id="volatile"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not the problem the code works fine. The problem is created after ajax filtering the products by attribute and doing that with another plug-in.

Comment: @BobCat I understood your question. The issue is that your button works until you do an ajax filter. That ajax filter actually appends to your HTML stuff and that breaks your event handlers.

Comment: @BobCat look at the first snippet I have given. There, when you click the button, it will work. Then the HTML is being appended and the click no longer works. It is a proof that when you append to your innerHTML, then the sibling buttons will lose their attached event handlers.

Comment: @BobCat when you do your `$('#container_products_more .products_archive_grid').append( data ); // where to insert posts` in the success callback of your AJAX filter, then the `.append()` function under the hood does an `.innerHTML += data` and that's completely destroying and recreating the content. Therefore your event handlers are lost.

Comment: So you suggest to put the button outside that container?

Comment: @BobCat I have provided four possible solutions. From these solutions the fourth is the one you have mentioned. But you have other options as well, according to what is most feasible for your scenario.